# How to delete unpopulated placeholder items using python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

This is very simple, but I cannot find the actual method anywhere in the documentation or otherwise.

I am using the python-pptx module and all I need to do is delete a single placeholder item, an empty text box, on some slides (without having to create a completely new layout just for these slides) - the closest thing to an answer is here: http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-understanding.html under **Unpopulated vs. populated** but it still does not say *how* to actually delete/remove the placeholder.

I've tried all the obvious methods .delete(), .remove(), etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no API support for this, but if you delete the text box shape element, that should do the trick. It would be something like this:

```
textbox = shapes[textbox_idx]
sp = textbox.element
sp.getparent().remove(sp)
```

Using the `textbox` variable/reference after this operation is not likely to go well. But otherwise, I expect this will do the trick.

Comment: Excellent - I only had to change what you gave slightly:

textbox = **slide**.shapes[textbox_idx]

with **slide** changing depending on the slide variable name.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I know this is old but I'm curious if there is working functionality to turn All Caps on or off for text; I'm able to do everything else, such as bold, italcis, underline, etc. as per http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html. Also mentioned on this same page is the ability to do this, but I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: @Jacristi: you should ask this as a separate, new question. It's not related to this topic. If you tag it with 'python-pptx' I'll see it and will be happy to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a follow-up to scanny's answer based on the helloworld example in the docs. The code deletes the subtitle placeholder, which is empty in this case.

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)

title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Hello, World!"

subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]
sp = subtitle.element
sp.getparent().remove(sp)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```