# How to remove content from placeholder?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Is there a method to remove an already inserted picture in a placeholder from a populated state to an unpopulated state through python rather than delete the image manually in powerpoint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete unpopulated placeholder items using python-pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603318/how-to-delete-unpopulated-placeholder-items-using-python-pptx)

Comment: Hmm no, because that one asks how to delete an unpopulated place holder. Im asking how to depopulate a placeholder that is currently populated so that it is unpopulated.